# AngularJs on finished rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying for hours, but with no luck at all. I have an angularjs application where i want to present the user with a loading spinner as long as the page is not fully loaded (rendered). Especially between state changes, because the click is registered, but nothing is happening right away. Thus the user is getting no feedback if it is actually loading or not. My application is requesting some data through ajax when the controller is getting executed.
I have already tried different solutions:

1. Using `$stateChangeStart` and `$viewContentLoaded`. This approach does work fine if the views are loaded for the first time, but fires too early for every subsequent state change. This has to do with the caching of templates. Every time the viewContentLoaded is fired the template is cached.
2. Using a directive with `$timeout`. This does work very well on the first load-up if i attach it to the `body` of my html document. But since i am using nested views/controllers the directive is not called again when i switch between states. It is once again fired to early when i attach the directive to the `ui-view`element.

Are there any alternatives? Am i doing something wrong? Is it even possible?

Thanks

Comment: can you share a plnk of your issue

Comment: Where exactly you load the data?

Comment: I am loading the data right when the controller is executed. The problem is that the loading is a asynchronous call and the directive is getting called as soon as the controller is finished executing, which does not mean that the data is actually already there. I will try to get an example working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the `resolve` object?

> You can use resolve to provide your controller with content or data that is custom to the state. resolve is an optional map of dependencies which should be injected into the controller.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve

Using `resolve` allows you to fetch your data before the controller is initialized. That way when your controller executes and `$viewContentLoaded` is fired you can be sure that your data is available:

```
$stateProvider.state('myState', {
    templateUrl: 'template.html',
    controller: function($scope, myData){
        $scope.myData = myData;
    },
    resolve:{
        myData:  function($http){
            return $http({method: 'GET', url: '/myUrl'})
                .then (function (data) {
                    return doSomeStuffFirst(data);
                }
            );
        }
    }
});
```

I bet when using `resolve` and your first option (using `$routeChangeStart` and `$viewContentLoaded` to set and remove your spinner) things will work a lot better than it does now.

Answer (score 0):

Create a div in your webapp where you want the spinner to display.

use an ng-show="loading"

Before your request set $scope.loading = true; then create an AngularJS promise which (using a .then() or .finally()) and in this .finally() put $scope.loading = false;

This way it shows your spinner while it's loading and when it's finally done it sets it to false which keeps it from showing.

Comment: I know how to do that just for one ajax request. The question i am asking is if it is possible to do that for the whole page. Thus when angularjs is finished working/rendering the DOM

Comment: What about `$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
    //Here your view content is fully loaded !!
  });` 

Or using a data-ng-init="loaded"?

Comment: Already tried `$viewContentLoaded` as stated above. Is fireing too early.EDIT: Should reiterate. It does work for the first time, but every subsequent state change is causing it to fire to early.

Comment: Send me your code in a GIST or something. I'll have to actually see it then.

Comment: I appreciate your offer, but sadly this is not possible. My solution for the moment is to just clear the template-cache every time the $viewContentLoaded is fired.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [angular-block-ui](http://angular-block-ui.nullest.com/), which is a module that takes care of displaying a *loading* indicator. Blocking can be done on the whole page or on individual elements. Behind the scenes it monitors http requests and determines if a block should be active (it ignores cached http requests).

Answer (score 0):

For someone.

```html
<div style="visibility: hidden;">
    {{MyVarAfterLoad = true}}
</div>
```